# SDL2 problem with displaying a texture in c

Tags: sdl-2

os : ArchLinux up to date.

Hello,
with this code :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* SDL */
    SDL_Window *fenetre = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *rendu = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;

    /* Init SDL */
    if(0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_Init : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    fenetre = SDL_CreateWindow(" Essai texture", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(NULL == fenetre)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateWindow : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    rendu = SDL_CreateRenderer(fenetre, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if(NULL == rendu)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateRenderer : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    /* Color */
    if(0 != SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rendu, 242, 243, 244, 255))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_SetRenderDrawColor : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    /* renderClear */
    if(0 != SDL_RenderClear(rendu))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_RenderClear : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    /* Create la texture */
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(rendu, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                                SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 400, 400);
    if(NULL == texture)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateTexture : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto Quit;
    }

    /* Colore la texture */
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(rendu, texture);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rendu, 242, 110, 160, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(rendu, NULL);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(rendu, NULL);

    /* Show texture in bottom */
    SDL_Rect dst = {50, 250, 400, 200};
    SDL_RenderCopy(rendu, texture, NULL, &dst);
    SDL_RenderPresent(rendu);
    SDL_Delay(3000); //

    /* And show texture in top */
    dst.y = 50;
    SDL_RenderCopy(rendu, texture, NULL, &dst);
    SDL_RenderPresent(rendu);
    SDL_Delay(3000);

Quit:
    if(NULL != texture)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    if(NULL != rendu)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(rendu);
    if(NULL != fenetre)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

at the second SDL_RenderPresent, the texture display works well but the window in the background is black.
With flag SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE in CreateRenderer, works well.

I try on debian, work well even with the flag SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED.

Someone had this little inconvenience with Archlinux and possibly a solution.

thank you in advance.

[First RenderPresent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyRVN.png)

[Second RenderPresent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnfZX.png)

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent "The backbuffer should be considered invalidated after each present; do not assume that previous contents will exist between frames"

Comment: Effectively that's it. So I have to redraw the whole window? Thanks a lot

Comment: Exactly. Not only that, you also have to redraw when OS asks you to; sleep is not a way to display things.

Comment: ok it is well noted. Thank you for these explanations.